# Numpy, Pandas Exercise

Tags: pandas, numpy

"[it just needs to be done using numpy and pandas.]"

Your task:
You are asked to write a function that applies ”slack time remaining” (STR) sequencing rule to a given collection of jobs. Although this rule has not been covered in class, application is very similar to critical ratio. You need to calculate STR value for all jobs and schedule the one with the lowest STR. Continue this until all jobs are scheduled. The STR values are calculated as follows:

```
STR = [Time Until Due Date] − [Processing Time]
```

If you have more than 1 job with the lowest STR, break ties with Earliest Due Date
(EDD) rule. If due dates are also the same, schedule the one arrived earlier (that means the one in the upper rows of the table.)
Your function will accept a single parameter as pandas dataframe:
Function Parameter:
df jobs: A pandas dataframe whose indexes are the names of the jobs. Jobs
are assumed to be arrived in the same day in the same order given in the dataframe. There
will be two data columns in the dataframe:
ˆ ”Processing Time”: Processing time required for the job
ˆ ”Due Date”: Time between arrival of the job and the due date of the job.
Output: Your function should return a list containing the correct sequence according to STR rule.
Example inputs and expected outputs:
Example Input Data:

```
Job Processing Time Due Date
A          2           7
B          8          16
C          4           4
D         10          17
E          5          15
F         12          18
```

Expected Output: `[’C’, ’A’, ’F’, ’D’, ’B’, ’E’]`

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your input is a `DataFrame` - your function would be:

```py
def str_list(df):
    df = df.set_index('Job')
    return (df['Due Date'] - df['Processing Time']).sort_values().index.tolist()
```